# API data not showing in table , Need to show with progress load(lazy load)

Tags: javascript, arrays, tabulator

API data not showing in table. Need to show with progress load(lazyload).
Here I have used tabulator plugin:

```js
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";
var myJsonString;
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    ajaxURL:"",
    ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
    return table.setData(response); 
    },
    ajaxProgressiveLoad:"scroll",
    paginationSize:20,
    placeholder:"No Data Set",
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"userId", sorter:"string", width:200},
        {title:"Progress", field:"progress", sorter:"number", formatter:"progress"},
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender", sorter:"string"},
        {title:"Rating", field:"rating", formatter:"star", align:"center", width:100},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col", sorter:"string"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
        {title:"Driver", field:"car", align:"center", formatter:"tickCross", sorter:"boolean"},
    ],
});
```

```html
**HTML tags are started here**
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.4.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.4.1/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Comment: What is the response?

Answer (score 0):

First off you dont appear to be telling the table which URL to use at any point.

If you dont set the url when you create the Tabulator you will need to set it by calling the ***setData*** function when you are ready to load data into the table

```js
table.setData("http://www.getmydata.com/now");
```

Also you definitely don't want to be doing anything in the ***ajaxResponse*** function, that is intended for manipulating data once it has been received, your code will likely cause an infinite loop, just remove that whole callback from your code your dont need it.

The Tabulator website contains a fully working [Ajax Example](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.4#ajax)

If you want to progressivly load data into the table, ie paginate your responses and load it into the table as the user scrolls then have a look at the [Progressive Loading Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/data#ajax-progressive)